# live editing field using best_in_place gem activator button on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, best-in-place

my comment list editing using best_in_place gem. therei's my code. just work it. But it failed when create new comment. also it works few minutes later and page refresh

%= comment :content type: :textarea, path: commen_path(comment), activator: "#activator-#{comment.id}" %>

('.best_in_place').best_in_place();  that code include best_in_place on js file.

maybe it include live binding... but how?

Comment: What was the error you got? Also notice that your path is wrong it should be `comment_path` not

Comment: it's work all comment list but best_in_place js not working new comment edit.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me with the following:

```
<% Comment.where(:user_id =>current_user.id).each do |comment| %>
  <%= best_in_place comment,:content %>
<%end%>
```